# Data to attributedString with font attributes Swift

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I have an RTF file with which I was able to get contents as Data (i want it to be in Data to use it elsewhere in code). Howeever, I would like to add styling to the attributedString like font before assigning to label. Im struck on how to apply these attributes in below code. Please advice how i can achieve same. Here's my code

```
let rtfData = getRTFData()
guard let data = rtfData else {
        return
    }
if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil) {
        myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
 }
```

Here i wanted to add attributes to attributedString like
`let boldAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)]` and apply these attributes to attributedText

Comment: Do you want to discard the original attributes (typeface) or only make the font bold and change its size?

Comment: i just want to make font bold and change its size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append font attribute to existing attributes this one should work:

```
if let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil) {
   var attrs = attributedString.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil)
   attrs[NSAttributedString.Key.font] = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
   attributedString.setAttributes(attrs, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
   myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
}
```